# How to concat variable to other variable in postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

In php connecting variable using `.` (dot), like `$a = "tes", $b="b"`, if
I connect `$a.$b` it becomes "tesb". I want this but in postgres

I have tried using dot and + but wrong

my code

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION make_ctx_contoh (rl varchar, dat varchar)
RETURNS numeric AS $total$
declare
date_before date;
dan text;
os_l numeric;
BEGIN
date_before = (DATE_TRUNC('month', NOW()) 
    + '0 MONTH'::INTERVAL 
    - '1 DAY'::INTERVAL)::DATE;
if rl = 'nasional' THEN
dan = '';
ELSEIF rl = 'kanwil' THEN
dan = 'AND LOWER(a."KANWIL") = knw';
ELSEIF rl = 'kc' THEN
dan = 'AND LOWER(a."KC") = kac';
END IF;
SELECT
    SUM("a"."OUTSTANDING") into os_l
    FROM
    "public".tbl_nominatif_hasil AS "a"
    WHERE
    "a"."BUSS_DATE" = date_before AND
    "a"."COLLDET" = '1 ' + dan; RETURN os_l;
END; $total$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

When I run select `make_ctx_contoh('kanwil','2');` that shows error like :

> ERROR:  operator does not exist: unknown + text LINE 6:
>   "a"."COLLDET" = '1 ' + dan

Comment: in SQL the concatenation operator is `||` but your concatenation isn't going to work even if you use the correct syntax. if you append a string to another that is not going to change the SQL the content of the column `coldet` will simply be compared to the string `'1 AND LOWER(a."KC") = kac'`. It won't magically add a different where condition.

Comment: `(DATE_TRUNC('month', NOW()) 
    + '0 MONTH'::INTERVAL 
    - '1 DAY'::INTERVAL)::DATE;` can be simplified to `current_date - 1`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name no its different result select current_date - 1,,, and select (DATE_TRUNC('month', NOW()) + '0 MONTH'::INTERVAL - '1 DAY'::INTERVAL)::DATE

Answer (score 0):

From what I could understand from your code, you want to add conditions to the where clause based on certain criteria.

So, convert your select query into a `AND` `OR` logic.

```
SELECT
    SUM("a"."OUTSTANDING") into os_l
       FROM "public".tbl_nominatif_hasil AS "a"
    WHERE "a"."BUSS_DATE" = date_before AND
    "a"."COLLDET" = 1 
    AND ( rl = 'nasional' OR 
        ( rl = 'kanwil' AND LOWER(a."KANWIL") = knw) OR
        ( rl = 'kc'     AND LOWER(a."KC") = kac')
        )
```

Comment: no its wrong. i want this when i select make_ctx_contoh('kanwil','2'); the query become SELECT
    SUM("a"."OUTSTANDING") into os_l
    FROM
    "public".tbl_nominatif_hasil AS "a"
    WHERE
    "a"."BUSS_DATE" = date_before AND
    "a"."COLLDET" = '1' AND LOWER(a."KANWIL") = knw; and when i select  make_ctx_contoh('kc','2'); the query become SELECT
    SUM("a"."OUTSTANDING") into os_l
    FROM
    "public".tbl_nominatif_hasil AS "a"
    WHERE
    "a"."BUSS_DATE" = date_before AND
    "a"."COLLDET" = '1' AND LOWER(a."KC") = 'kac';